# Datetime sorting very slow on postgresql

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I have a review table which has, `app_id(string), reviews_updated_at(timestamp), description(text)` and other stuff. The table has around 90 million entries, I have around 2000 read IOPS limit on my database instance and the below mentioned query takes 30-40 sec to complete, Is there any way i can make this query execute faster?.

I have two indexes `app_id(btree)`, `reviews_updated_at(btree)`

Query:

```
select * from reviews
where app_id = '2332223'
order by review_updated_at
offset 200 limit 100
```

Query Plan:

```
Limit  (cost=243270.84..364905.97 rows=100 width=258) (actual time=23212.698..32806.020 rows=100 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using index_reviews_on_review_updated_at on reviews  (cost=0.57..327489222.63 rows=269239 width=258) (actual time=237.720..32805.359 rows=300 loops=1)
        Filter: ((app_id)::text = '2332223'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 36376
Planning time: 0.160 ms
Execution time: 32806.216 ms
```

Comment: To make it run faster, add a where clause so there are fewer records to sort.

Comment: ap_is seems to be an integer. remove the quotes -> `WHERE ap_id = 2332223` (and maybe your statistics are off)

Comment: @DanBracuk what where clause? These are the records that I want.

Comment: @wildplasser In some cases it's integer, In others it is not. The column type is string.

Comment: The 2000 IOPS limit - what do you think how many disk pages you can read in a second? And can you try this query on some real hardware?

Comment: @A.Scherbaum what do you mean by some real hardware, what would you suggest?

Comment: Are you sure that your slow performance is not caused by the IOPS limit?

Comment: @A.Scherbaum Now I am sure, because after making composite index, it's very fast.

Comment: And what is the cost (in EXPLAIN) for the new index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this query:

```
select *
from reviews
where app_id = '2332223'
order by review_updated_at
offset 200
limit 100;
```

The best index in `reviews(app_id, review_updated_at)`.  Actually with this index, the query should be quite fast.

Note that when comparing values, you should ensure that they are of the same type.  If `app_id` is a string, then there should be quotes.

Comment: which values should be of the same type?

Comment: The `app_id` and the value it is being compared to.

Comment: The datatype for app_id is string, most of the app_ids in the table are strings, only some of them are numbers.

Comment: Thanks, it's very fast now using composite index.